# Proper use of EOF (can it be used multiple times in a program?)

Tags: c++

In my intro to programming course (c++), the instructor told us to:

> "Write a program that inputs an unspecified number of integer ("int")
>   values and then outputs the minimum value and the maximum value that
>   were entered. At least one value will always be input. (read all input
>   until EOF). For extra credit make your program also work when the user
>   doesn't enter any ints at all (just the EOF.)"

I wanted to get fancy, so, in my solution, when just `EOF` is entered, the program responds with `"Oops! You didn't enter anything. Please try again, this time entering at least one integer: "` and prompts for input again.

My instructor is saying that this answer is wrong because

> After the EOF, there should be no more input to a program (neither
>   expected by the user nor the program) — using the `EOF` to switch from
>   “one mode” of input to another mode of input isn’t supporting the
>   standards.

1. Every definition of `EOF` I've found on the internet doesn't seem to support my professor's definition. `EOF`, from what I can tell, is simply defined as the end of the current file. It seems perfectly valid to accept input from a user until `EOF`, do something with that input, and then ask for additional input until `EOF` again.
2. Because this is an online course, I was able to review everything we learned relating to `EOF` and we were only told that `EOF` meant "End of File" and could be 'used to signal an end to user input' (important, because, even if my professor was wrong, one could argue that I should have adopted his standards if he had specifically told us to. But he didn't tell us to).

**What is the proper way to use `EOF` with user input? Is my professor's statement that "After the EOF, there should be no more input to a program" the standard
 and expected way to use EOF? If a program accepts a variable amount of input, does something with it, and then accepts more variable input, is it not acceptable to use `EOF` with those inputs (aka don't use `while(cin >> user_input)` in that scenerio)? If so, is there a standard for what should be used to signal end of input in a scenario where you're accepting variable input multiple times?**

My exact solution to the assignment is below. My solution to the main assignment "Write a program that inputs an unspecified number of integer ("int") values and then outputs the minimum value and the maximum value that were entered" was considered correct, by the second part of the assignment "make your program also work when the user doesn't enter any ints at all (just the EOF.)" was deemed incorrect ("make the program also work" is the only prompt we were given).

Thanks so much for any feedback!! Obviously, I'm skeptical of my professors feedback / decision, but, in general, I'm just trying to get a sense of C++ community standards.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){
  string user_input;

  int int_input, min_user_input, max_user_input;
  bool do_it = true;

  cout << "Hi John," << endl;
  cout << "Please enter a few integers (signal EOF when finished): ";

  while(do_it) {
    cin.clear();
    cin >> user_input;

    if (user_input.empty()) {
      cout << endl;
      cout << "Oops! You didn't enter anything. Please try again, this time entering at least one integer: ";
    }
    else {
      try {
        int_input = atoi( user_input.c_str() );

        min_user_input = int_input;
        max_user_input = int_input;

        while(cin >> int_input) {
          if (min_user_input > int_input) {
            min_user_input = int_input;
          }

          if (max_user_input < int_input) {
            max_user_input = int_input;
          }
        }

        cout << endl;
        cout << "The max user input was: " << max_user_input << endl;
        cout << "The min user input was: " << min_user_input << endl;
        do_it = false;
      }
      catch (std::invalid_argument) {
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Oops! You didn't enter an integer. Please try again, this time only entering integers: ";
        do_it = true;
      }
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

*Note: additional feedback I got on this submission was: to not use c libraries (apparently `stdlib.h` is one) and that, on some computers (though, apparently, not mine), `#include <stdexcept>` will be needed to compile.*

## Answer

Short answer: my instructor is correct. When used with `cin`, no additional user input should follow an `EOF` signal. Apparently, in some cases the program won't let you enter more information, but, as @hvd points out

> Although your system may let you continue reading from the same file
>   in the specific case that it is coming from a TTY, due to EOF being
>   faked there, you shouldn't generally rely on that.

Aka, because I'm using a terminal to enter user input, the program happens to work. In general, it won't work though.

As @RSahu answers, EOF just shouldn't be used to signal the end of variable length `cin` multiple times in a program. Importantly

> There is no standard means, or commonly practiced coding standard, of
>   indicating when user input has ended for the time being. You'll have
>   to come up with your own mechanism. For example, if the user enters
>   "end", you can use it to deduce that the user has ended input for the
>   time being. However, you have to indicate to the user that that's what
>   they need to enter. Of course, you have to write code to deal with
>   such input.

Because this assignment required the use of EOF, what I was attempting to accomplish was, unintentionally, prohibited (aka receive input, check it, possibly receive more input).

Comment: "`EOF`, from what I can tell, is simply defined as the end of the current file. It seems perfectly valid to accept input from a user until `EOF`, do something with that input, and then ask for additional input until `EOF` again." -- Huh? It seems perfectly valid to you to accept input until end of file, do something with it, and then continue reading from that same file? What do you think "end" means?

Comment: @hvd, I think that `while(cin >> user_input) ...do stuff ... while(cin >> user_input_again) ... do more stuff` is, conceptually, receiving input from two different files / sources. You end the first one with `EOF`, it's conceptually consistent to end the second one with `EOF`.

Comment: But it's `cin` in the first loop, it's `cin` in the second loop, and there has been no code in between to suggest that `cin` starts to refer to a different file.

Comment: @John EOF is an *out of band signal*, ie when the pipe/stream is closed. It is not part of any data stream and represents a state in which that channel is well .. finished. In this case that is the STDIN. The "next record" needs to be communicated via other means (that doesn't kill said pipe/stream that is being consumed and/or a *new* pipe/stream needs to be opened), maybe a newline or an EOT ASCII character or..

Comment: @user2864740, so then, is it fair to say that `EOF` should *never* be used when receiving user input from a keyboard--at least, if that input is of variable length (i.e., you don't know until the input is processed whether you want more or not)? It's non-standard to use EOF with `cin` if you ever have a scenerio  like this `while(cin >> user_input) ...do stuff ... while(cin >> user_input_again) ... do more stuff`? Also, really thanks for the prompt feedback!! @user2864740 && @hvd

Comment: @user2864740, perhaps the issue is that, in all of our recent user_input assignments we've been told to end user input with EOF, so I interpreted that as the standard way of terminating user input. In most programs, you'll be receiving a lot of user input however so EOF will not commonly be used? (until it really is the end, obviously)

Comment: *is, conceptually, receiving input from two different files / sources* No, it is not, conceptually or otherwise. What happens here is the *terminal* lets you continue reading after EOF. Most other kinds of input devices won't. Terminals in different kinds of OS may or may not do that. You shouldn't expect your program will be ran on a partucular OS with a particular kind of input file.

Comment: @n.m. Thanks! That fact was being lost on me. Because the terminal continued accepting input after `EOF`, I didn't think of the terminal stream as *one file*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Proper use of EOF (can it be used multiple times in a program?)

There is no single EOF. There is EOF associated with every input stream.

If you are reading from a file, you can reset the state of the `std::ifstream` when it reaches EOF to allow you to read the contents of the file again.

However, if you are reading data from `std::cin`, once EOF is reached, you can't read from `std::cin` any more.

In the context of your program, your professor is right. They are most likely talking about reading from `std::cin`.

Comment: I'm interpreting "once EOF is reached, you can't read from std::cin any more." to mean "*shouldn't* read from std::cin any more" (because it does work). I thought my use of `cin.clear();` resets `EOF` for cin? Why isn't it conceptually acceptable to ask for input again after clearing `cin`? The sense I'm getting is that `EOF` just shouldn't be used to signal the end of variable length user input from a terminal.

Comment: @John, I mean *can't*, not *shouldn't*. Use of `cin.clear()` clears error states but it does not reset the EOF state of `cin`. For example, if you were trying to read an integer but the input was not an integer, `cin` would be in a state of error. `cin.clear()` will clear that state. *The sense I'm getting is that EOF just shouldn't be used to signal the end of variable length user input from a terminal.*  -- That is correct.

Comment: Ah ya, I forgot `cin.clear()` is used in case `atoi()` throws an exception. Thanks for all the info! When a program is accepting variable length user input, is there a standard means in c++ of indicating user input has ended *for the time being* (another character, perhaps)?

Comment: @John, use of `cin.clear()` when `atoi` throws an exception is ill founded. State of `cin` has no relation to what `atoi` does. There is no standard means, or commonly practiced coding standard, of indicating when user input has ended for the time being. You'll have to come up with your own mechanism. For example, if the user enters "end", you can use it to deduce that the user has ended input for the time being. However, you have to indicate to the user that that's what they need to enter. Of course, you have to write code to deal with such input.

Answer (score 1):

> `EOF`, from what I can tell, is simply defined as the end of the current file.

It is. Note that in particular, what it doesn't mean is the automatic start of a new file.

Although your system may let you continue reading from the same file in the specific case that it is coming from a TTY, due to `EOF` being faked there, you shouldn't generally rely on that. Try `program </dev/null` and see happens when you try to automate your program.

Comment: I wrote this a while ago, but I believe I'm resetting `EOF` with my use of `cin.clear()`? Which allows me to accept user input again. Basically, my program analyses the input and, when invalid, says "that was invalid, try again" and resets everything (or at least, that's my goal). But what I'm interpreting from your answer is that I should not attempt to do this in c++? The proper way would be to validate data before ending the file? Requiring me to use some other method for ending user input? Is there a standard character in c++ for that? Thanks for the help!!!

Comment: Nvm, just remembered that `cin.clear()` is being used in case `atoi()` throws an exception.